# Database undefined error in phonegap android?

Tags: android, database, cordova

I am getting database: undefined in phonegap with android. I am creating some tables in phonegap and after successful creation of tables it gives me the database undefined error. please help. i am new to phonegap. code -

```
var db; 
var dbCreated = false; 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
function onDeviceReady() { 
  //alert("In Device Ready..."); 
  db = window.openDatabase("sgpw", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000); 
  db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success); 
}
```

Comment: var db;
var dbCreated = false;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
 //alert("In Device Ready...");
    db = window.openDatabase("sgpw", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);
}

Comment: Hi, I am trying to execute query like this below and i am getting error "undefined"... Code : sqlProposal = "select * from proposal ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";  tx.executeSql(sqlProposal, [], getProposal_success); any idea?

Comment: You need to post more code. You said your error is AFTER the table setup, right? You only posted part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem when was new to phonegap.
Try this ,

```
var db = window.openDatabase("sgpw", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000); 

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() { 

db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_error, populateDB_success);

}
```

This will then call `populateDB` function. 

If error comes then will call `transaction_error`.
If successful then will call `populateDB_success` function.